# Should statsmodels's GLM produce the same results as R's lm?

Tags: python, r, logistic

Should Python's

```
statsmodels.api.GLM(train_y, train_X, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit().predict(test_X)
```

always produce the same results as R's

```
predict(glm(y ~ ., data=train_X, family=binomial), newdata=test)
```

where `train_y` is a pandas `DataFrame` containing the `y` column in the corresponding R `data.frame`, `train`; and where `test_X` and `train_X` are dataframes containing the remaining columns from the `test` and `train` dataframes respectively?

If not, are there parameters that I can supply to `statsmodels`'s `GLM` to make it produce the same results as R's `glm`?

Comment: Note: This is just a question about whether these *should* produce the same results, not about what might be going wrong if they should  but don't. That would be a new, follow-on question.

Comment: This question strikes me as being more about the underlying theory in statistics, rather than about how to program R & Python. I believe it is better suited to Cross Validated (stats.SE) than here.

Comment: @gung: I think it's just about whether the API should behave the same (and every time I post on CV, they move my question here).

Comment: I understand your frustration, it can be difficult to determine which site is best, both for askers & for reviewers. Recognize that our goal is always just to help you get the best answer & to keep the sites optimally organized for future information seekers. I certainly could be wrong here, but I still think this Q fits better on CV. We'll see what the moderators say.

Comment: @gung: No problem. I'm fine with moving it there.

Comment: One thing to double check is that they are indeed fitting the same model.  I haven't used the python package you mention but I know some packages don't incorporate an intercept term by default.  R does include an intercept term by default.  I haven't used python's version so I can't say if that is what might be causing differences but it's something to double check.

Comment: @Dason: Great point (I'm new to this). How do I add an intercept to my Python model?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't even know if that's an issue.  I just know that some packages don't default to adding an intercept for you so it's always good to check if you are indeed fitting the same model.  Hopefully somebody else that knows statsmodels will come along and comment either telling you to ignore me (because you are fitting the same models) or how to fit an intercept term with your model.

Comment: @Dason: Whether it's the cause, I do think it's a factor (no pun): I don't see an intercept in the Python `params`.

Comment: You can force an intercept by including a column of 1s in your predictors.

Comment: @Dason: Interesting, a Python model with an intercept does not converge, just like the R one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they should give the same answers if you fit the same model. Compare

R code

```
cuse <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat", 
                   header=TRUE)
attach(cuse)
mod <- glm(cbind(using, notUsing) ~ age + education + wantsMore , family= binomial)
summary(mod)
```

Python code

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

cuse = pd.read_table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat",
                     sep=" +")
res = sm.formula.glm("using + notUsing ~ C(age, Treatment('<25')) + "
                     "education + wantsMore",  family=sm.families.Binomial(), 
                     data=cuse).fit() 
res.summary()
```

If there's a convergence issue here, I wouldn't trust either answer without knowing why there are convergence issues. I'd be interested to have a look at some data that can reproduce these convergence failures in R.

Comment: I'm working on getting permission to post the data; not looking good.

Comment: "Should" applies to regular cases, up to convergence tolerance. However, in "irregular" cases like near singular design matrix or perfect separation, the difference in implementation will show up. But then the statistical result is ambiguous anyway.

Comment: Could it be that Python is "succeeding" where R is "failing": R gives me a useless model with every one of 300 variables highly significant, while Python gives me one, that matches the first branch of a CART model on the same data?

Comment: Also, I can't use `formula`: I have a column called 'break' that always causes `File "<string>", line 1
    break
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: And `sm.GLM(train.Y, train[columns], family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()` gives me different results than `sm.formula.glm('Y ~ ' + '+'.join(columns), data=tweets_train, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()`. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Given the above comments by @Dason, I assume you don't have an intercept in `train[columns]` while the formula adds one by default. If you use `GLM`, then the design matrix is all yours and statsmodels doesn't change it. Using `formula.glm` adds an intercept and converts any `factor` variables to a dummy or other encoding by default.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that they shouldn't always produce identical results, although the difference in the results would almost always be negligible.  When trying to fit non-linear GLiMs (such as a logistic regression), there is no closed form solution for estimating the betas as there is in OLS regression.  Instead, a search algorithm is used.  Typically this is the [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) [gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) method.  As far as I know, there is no absolute guarantee that this will yield identical results, and small differences in the way it's implemented in different languages behind the scenes could cause small differences in outputs.  However, unless there is some strong ambiguity in the data, I would suspect any differences would not show up for several decimal places; that is, well after the point where people would have rounded anyway.

Comment: Accuracy of `0.802816901` (R) vs `0.745042493` (Python).

Comment: FWIW, If I start from scratch and build and preprocess my data in Python (split the same as in R, but otherwise managed from the start in Python) I get `0.742209632`. I'd expect some subtle differences here (I'm tokenizing text); but the *big* difference between what R and Python do with the *same* data (same tokenization) is surprising (to me).

Comment: Hmmm... that's a larger difference than I would have expected. If the sole issue is in the estimation of the betas, it would imply that R's estimated betas are better optimized. It should also be possible to input different starting points to the optimization in both, & to request different optimization algorithms in both to see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, looking more closely, here's what I see: Nearly *all* of the R model's (more than 300!) p-values are highly significant (`<2e-16`), while only *one* of the Python model's is (at `0.025236`), and that one corresponds to the first branch of the CART tree fitted to the same data. Also, R produces "does not converge" warnings. I'm not sure what all that means (I'm new to this) but it seems like Python is doing a lot better job of coming up with a usable model (is R overfitting?).

Comment: Is your Python model a CART? Your R model is logistic regression. You shouldn't expect that these would given identical responses b/c they are different models.

Comment: No, the CART model is a *different model on the same data*.

Comment: OK. It's hard for me to know what's going on in your data. If the accuracy is based on holdout data, it shouldn't indicate overfitting. There are a couple of general things to hold in mind, though. 1) Do some troubleshooting w/ different optimizations to make sure you're getting convergence. 2) Accuracy is not the best way to optimize b/c it is based on an arbitrary threshold; try the area under the ROC curve (AUC) instead. 3) You'll want to do cross validation where you use different subsets as holdout data, rotate over them & repeat, then average, rather than use a single holdout set.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the data: I'm working on getting permission to post it, but don't have much hope.

Comment: Isn't the fact that the Python GLM gives a high p-value (only) for the first branch of the CART on the same data an indication that the GLM is a good model (assuming the CART is a good one)? (I have some null values in my data so Python's `roc_curve` is not happy with me.)